# Centering div block relative to this center

Tags: html, css

I want to set the gemoetrical center of my div block at the geometrical center of the screen. How i can do that? Let we have

```
<div style="position: absolute; width: 240px; height: 150px; margin:50%; >
    some content
</div>
```

But it doesn't work. I dont undestand why it doesnt. `margin:50%` equivalent to `margin-top/left/right/bottom: 50%`. Thus we have extra space to our `div` element as `50%` of linear screen size. Why it is neccesary to define the `width` and `height` explicitly if we use `margin` attribute or `top/left/right/bottom` attributes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use the following:

```
<div style="position: absolute; margin: auto; width: 240px; height: 150px; top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;">
    some content
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here we go. The HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="centered">Hello</div>
</body>
```

The CSS:

```
.centered {
    position: absolute;
    width: 240px; 
    height: 150px;
    /* positioning the element (top/left corner) at the center */
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    /* moving the element's center to the screen's center (compensating relatively to the dimensions) */
    margin-top: -75px; /* half of the height */
    margin-left: -120px; /* half of the width */
}
```

`margin: 50%` won't work because of elements with `position: absolute` lose the reference to the parent's dimensions. This is one of the various layout problems with the CSS Box Model.

However, you can use the Flexbox Layout Model, that would be a **lot** easier:

```
body {
    display: flex;
}

.centered {
    margin: auto;
}
```

You just need to set `margin: auto` and the parent element must be set as `display: flex`. Simple =)

Answer (score 0):

Use the below to make it centralized.

**For Instance,**

```
<div style="display: table; margin: 0px auto;">
    <div style="margin: 0px auto; text-align: center; background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% gray; width: 240px; height: 150px; display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;">
        some content
    </div>
</div>
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/n2Ctw/1/)**

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But it's horizontal alignment only. I need in vertical alignment to.

Comment: Added the same in my answer above. Hope this helps.

Comment: It doesnt work. Div block located at the top-left screen angle.

Comment: It works on my fiddle on browsers. Show me your screenshot of how you want and how it is gettin displayed - @DmitryFucintv